# dual of sub problem is infeasible, What should we do?

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, mixed-integer-programming

i have this problem 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; c^Tx + b^Ty\\
s.t. & \; Ax  \ge d\\
& \; Bx +Dy \ge h\\
& \; y\ge0, x\in\mathbb{X}
\end{split}
\label{OP}
\end{equation}

i want to solve it by benders decomposition method,  if dual of sub problem be infeasible , What should i do? Is the algorithm terminated?

in benders decomposition  suppose 
 master problem is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; c^Tx + \phi\\
s.t. & \;Ax  \ge d\\
& \;  x\in\mathbb{X}
\end{split}
\label{OP1}
\end{equation}

and sub problem is :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; b^Ty \\
s.t.&\;  Dy \ge h- Bx\\
& \;y\ge0
\end{split}
\label{OP3}
\end{equation}

we can write  sub problem as (dual of sub problem):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\max &\; \pi ^T (h- B x) \\
s.t.&\;  \pi ^T D \le b\\
& \;\pi\ge0
\end{split}
\label{OP8}
\end{equation}

i think in this situation We can not continue the algorithm,  is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always avoid the dual subproblem being infeasible by adding bounds to the primal variables (which, if you’re modeling something realistic, is always possible).

Suppose you have the LP

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max\ & c^Tx \\
\text{s.t.}\ & Ax\leqslant{b}
\end{array}
$$

with corresponding dual

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & b^Ty \\
\text{s.t.}\ & y^TA=c^T\\
&y\geqslant0
\end{array}
$$

Well, this dual may be infeasible. So what if we add some upper and lower bounds to the primal instead? Then

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max\ & c^Tx \\
\text{s.t.}\ & Ax\leqslant{b}\\
& x\geqslant\ell \\
& x\leqslant{u}
\end{array}
$$

Then the dual problem is

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & b^Ty+u^Tz^+-\ell^Tz^- \\
\text{s.t.}\ & y^TA+(z^+-z^-)=c^T\\
&y\geqslant0\\
&z^\pm\geqslant0
\end{array}
$$

This dual problem is guaranteed to be feasible. Do you see why?

Comment: How can I find these boundaries?

Comment: It completely depends on the problem. For computation, it’s a bad idea to pick very large numbers without a good reason. You usually need to look at the thing you’re modeling and decide or calculate the bounds.

Comment: @ِ David M. ok , thanks . by $z^+ ,z^-$  dual problem always  to be feasible because If we have a shortage, $z^+$ will be taken
And if we have a surplus,$ z^-$ will count, right?

Comment: That’s the idea, yes

Comment: @ David M  thanks a lot , good time :-)